# TransactionAbortedException in TestInitialize

Tags: c#, unit-testing, vs-unit-testing-framework

I have a base class for my unit tests which sets up a simple transaction around every test.

```
public class TestBase
{
    TransactionScope _trans;

    [TestInitialize()]
    public void Init()
    {
        _trans = new TransactionScope();
    }

    [TestCleanup()]
    public void Cleanup()
    {
        _trans.Dispose();
    }
}
```

In one of my inheriting classes I have a bunch of work I want to do once, before any of those tests are run - this should roll back after all tests for the class are completed.

```
 [TestClass]
public class MyTests : TestBase
{
    static TransactionScope  _transClass;
    [ClassInitialize()]
    public static void ClassInit(TestContext context)
    {
        _transClass = new TransactionScope();
      //do some setup
    }

    [ClassCleanup()]
    public static void ClassCleanup()
    {
        _transClass.Dispose();
    }

    [TestMethod()]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        //do some testing
    }
}
```

My actual class has multiple test methods of course.  The first test method passes fine, but the second throws a  TransactionAbortedException when it tries to set up a new TransactioScope in TestInitialize.  Could someone please explain what I have set up wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the base class `TestBase` may be doing something with the connection after each test.

It's best to use transactions with `using` statement - it eliminates problems like yours.

Also having multiple tests in a single transaction is not a good idea, this means that the tests are interdependent. This leads to hard to track issues when a test passes or fails depending if it's run in a group or on its own.

In summary, I advice against having a member field for the transaction and instead use local variables with the `using` statement.